# Switch case is not working on negative check

Tags: php

I have no idea why my switch case is not executed

```
$t1 = $nextFeed;
$t2 = date("m/d/Y h:i:s a", time());

$timeLeftTowardNextFeed = strtotime($t1) - strtotime($t2); 
$timeLeftTowardNextFeed = $timeLeftTowardNextFeed / ( 60 * 60 );


dd($timeLeftTowardNextFeed); // -6.0533333333333


switch (true) {
    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed > 1:
    $timleftColor = '#00ff5c';
    break;

    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 1:
    $timleftColor = '#ffc51b';
    break;

    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 0:
    $timleftColor = '#c12222'; <<-------------------------------------------------- should executed 
    break;

    default:
    $timleftColor = 'white';
    break;
}
```

---

```
// -6.0533333333333
if($timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 0){
    dd("HERE"); // It ran 
}
```

So as you can see.. if work, but switch does not.

The value is negative

What did I missed ?

Comment: Can you provide `$nextFeed` value?

Comment: Because case already works prior to that condition `case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 1`

Comment: `case` evaluates the expression *immediately*, before branching, so these all boil down to `true` or `false`. You can only use `switch` for straight equivalence tests, not range-based comparisons. Using it like this on `true` is really not what `switch` was intended for. This should be converted to an `if` chain.

Comment: Only the code of one `case` is executed, the first one that matches the `switch` expression. Any value that is `< 0` is also `< 1`, therefore the case `$timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 0` is never evaluated. It should work if you change the order of the cases but it's better to use conditions that do not overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Missing a condition> 0 to not meet the second case ...

```
switch (true) {
    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed > 1:
    $timleftColor = '#00ff5c';
    break;

    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 1 && $timeLeftTowardNextFeed >=0:
    $timleftColor = '#ffc51b';
    break;

    case $timeLeftTowardNextFeed < 0:
    $timleftColor = '#c12222';
    break;

    default:
    $timleftColor = 'white';
    break;
}
```

Comment: This is increasingly irregular code. Conditions **do not** belong in `case` expressions.